# How to change text dynamically in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

We need to change text dynamically "zeroRecords" in Language.

I have tried in `fnDrawCallback`:

```
userTable.fnSettings().language= {"zeroRecords":"Now empty"};
```

**Edit :**

I need to display message like " something {variable} something {variable 2}, where variable value are picked from hidden input or pass through response.

Answer (score 2):

At the time this is written, referring to latest version 1.10.12, you still cannot change none plugin language strings without reinitialising the dataTable. But since you are referring to `zeroRecords` you can change the content dynamically. dataTables inserts a special `<tr>` containing only one `<td>` :

```html
<td colspan="#colcount" class="dataTables_empty">...</td>
```

So you can easily overwrite the content in a `draw.dt` event handler :

```js
var someVar = 'this is a dynamic variable';

table.on('draw.dt', function() {
  var $empty = $('#example').find('.dataTables_empty');
  if ($empty) $empty.html('Now empty : ' + someVar)
})
```

see **http://jsfiddle.net/1273zafx/** and click <kbd>clear</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:

This is a example.

```
var langFile = "../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.en-US.txt";  

var oTable = $('.gvDataTable').dataTable({  
    "oLanguage": {  
        "sUrl": langFile  
    },  
    "sScrollX": "99%",    
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {/*Re-Create serial no for the table*/  
        /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */  
        if (oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered) {  
            for (var i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aiDisplay.length; i < iLen; i++) {  
                $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[oSettings.aiDisplay[i]].nTr).html(i + 1);  
            }  
        }  
         /*Put checkboxlist after filter to show/hide columns after excel export*/  
        $('.cbShowOrHideGvCols').appendTo('div.DTTT_container');   
    },  

});
```

Refer:http://asp-tech.blogspot.com/2013/11/jquery-datatables-change-language.html

Comment: No actually I need to display message like " something {variable} something {variable 2}. I'm not sure whether we can implement using your code. Variable value should be picked from hidden value.